# For-Loop - value of i is not 0 even if code says 'int i = 0'. i = BIG number, why? How to fix?

Tags: c++

I'm designing a program to clean up a text file that contains code. It removes comments, excess spaces/lines, and creates a new line for lines in the file with multiple semi-colons.

I actually got this program to work, but it used arrays.  Since I am working on another program that builds on this, except with a more diverse size of data inputs, I'm converting it to use vectors instead of standard arrays so I can re-purpose the program...which is kind of the point.

My problem is that after the program iterates through the first for-loop, the rest of the for-loops initialize the iterator with a value of '3435973836', regardless of proper declaration ('int i = 0', 'int k = 0', etc).  I declare them unsigned and omitting singed/unsigned still initializes the value incorrectly (-858993460).

This does 1 of 2 things:

1. unsigned the loop never starts as the value is too high to start the loop.
2. omitting makes the loop run for a long, long time.

Any thoughts?  I've posted the code below.  Please ignore any other errors I've made other than this, as I have been unable to get past this to debug anything else.

EDIT --> SOLVED: the problem that I was passing the vectors by value. But even when I changed it to pass by reference the program would still not work. The actual problem was with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. Once I PBV once, it corrupted my project.  I had to start a new VS project and insert the code.  If you do this, be careful you don't run the program while still PBV or you'll have to do it again.  I don't know why this happens.  Maybe somebody who knows MS Visual Studio could answer that.
Thanks again community!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void removeComments(vector<string> row, ifstream & myfile);
void sortLines (vector<string> row);
//void cleanCode (vector<string> row);

int main()
{
    vector<string> row;
    ifstream myfile;

    //Open txt file
    myfile.open("newdata.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()) 
    {
        //Remove comments, create proper lines, and remove/add spaces.
        removeComments(row, myfile);
        sortLines(row);
        //cleanCode(row);
    }

    else 
    {
        cout<< "ERROR: No file was able to open.  Check the file name or location and try again."<< endl << endl;
    }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< row[i] << endl;
    }

    cout<< endl;
    myfile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

//FUNCTIONS


//Removes all comments.
void removeComments(vector<string> row, ifstream & myfile)
{

    string line;

    while(getline(myfile, line))
    {
        string tempString;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            //Copy characters to row string array until "//".
            //All character following and including "//" will be ignored.
            if(line.at(i) == '/' && line.at(i+1) == '/')
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                tempString += line.at(i);
            }
        }

        row.push_back(tempString);
    }



}

//Creates a new line after every semi-colon.
void sortLines (vector<string> row)
{
    vector<string> tempRow;
    string tempLine;
    string tempString;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
    {
        tempLine = row [i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < tempLine.length(); j++)
        {
            tempString += tempLine[j];
            if (tempLine[j] == ';')
            {
                tempRow.push_back(tempString);
            }
        }
    }

    //Revalue row array elements.

    //DEBUGGING OUTPUT
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tempRow.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< tempRow[i] << endl;
    }

    row.clear();
    row = tempRow;

}
```

Okay, this is my by-reference edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void removeComments(vector<string> &row, ifstream & myfile);
void sortLines (vector<string> &row);
//void cleanCode (vector<string> &row);

int main()
{
    vector<string> row;
    ifstream myfile;

    //Open txt file
    myfile.open("newdata.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()) 
    {
        //Remove comments, create proper lines, and remove/add spaces.
        removeComments(row, myfile);
        sortLines(row);
        //cleanCode(row);
    }

    else 
    {
        cout<< "ERROR: No file was able to open.  Check the file name or location and try again."<< endl << endl;
    }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< row[i] << endl;
    }

    cout<< endl;
    myfile.close();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

//FUNCTIONS


//Removes all comments.
void removeComments(vector<string> &row, ifstream & myfile)
{

    string line;
    while(getline(myfile, line))
    {
        string tempString;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            //Copy characters to row string array until "//".
            //All character following and including "//" will be ignored.
            if(line.at(i) == '/' && line.at(i+1) == '/')
            {
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                tempString += line.at(i);
            }
        }

        row.push_back(tempString);
    }



}

//Creates a new line after every semi-colon.
void sortLines (vector<string> &row)
{
    vector<string> tempRow;
    string tempLine;
    string tempString;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++)
    {
        tempLine = row [i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < tempLine.length(); j++)
        {
            tempString += tempLine[j];
            if (tempLine[j] == ';')
            {
                tempRow.push_back(tempString);
            }
        }
    }

    //Revalue row array elements.

    //DEBUGGING OUTPUT
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tempRow.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< tempRow[i] << endl;
    }

    row.clear();
    row = tempRow;

}
```

Comment: Can you remove as much code as possible while keeping the problem there, and post the shortened version?

Comment: To start with, your vectors are being passed by value.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is, so I don't know what to cut.  every for loop is skipped after the first does this.  Any suggestions on where to cut?  Anything to make it easier.

Comment: @LazyBear You keep cutting until the problem disappears. Then you remove the last cut.

Comment: The problem sounds like stack corruption. If you stop passing vectors by value (which is wrong anyway cos you're trying to modify them) then I bet the problem goes away.

Comment: @FredOverflow  Okay, I cut the last 3 functions off the bottom and left the top 2.  The forloop in removeComments works, but the loop in sortLines is the first place this occurs.

Comment: @T.C. ,Adrian May   Okay, I'll try passing by reference and get back to you.   Thanks so far.

Comment: @FredOverflow Okay, I passed all of my vectors by reference and I'm still getting this problem.

Comment: @LazyBear but you still use `k` instead of `i`?

Comment: @Adrian May I am trying to get the function to directly edit the vector.  Why wouldn't I want to modify the vector?  Is there a better method getting the edits made to 'row' by the function to main?

Comment: @Wimmel  Haha, sorry! I just edited what I had to reflect the changes I made in my code.  I'll change that back to i.

Comment: @LazyBear Please copy-paste always exactly what you use. It would not be the first time the error is in a part which you forgot to copy. You still use `k` after your two edits....

Comment: >Why wouldn't I want to modify the vector?< Sorry: it's fine that you're editing the vector, but then you must pass it by reference.

Comment: `line.at(i++) == '/'` should be `line.at(i+1) == '/'`

Comment: I really appreciate the help so far guys...really.  Okay, I've made all the the changes and they should be reflected in the posted code above.  But I'm still getting this problem.  Does anyone get this?  I mean, this isn't a complicated program by any stretch and these are simple for-loops. I've never had the program ignore a clear declaration like this. If I code 'i = 0'in a for-loop...shouldn't 'i = 0'?  Even when I step through the debugger, it's almost like the program is ignoring the code that says 'i = 0' then does it's own thing. Just weird, but I'm also very curious to learn the cause.

Comment: I SOLVED IT! And a bunch of people here helped! Okay, the problem WAS that I was passing by value, but even when I changed it the code would not work.  The actual problem was with Microsoft Visual Studio.  Once I PBV once, it corrupted my project.  No matter what I did to the code, for-loops would not work.  So I plugged the code into a new project (which I tried before posting to stackoverflow), and it worked.  Then, just to see what would happen, I deleted the &s from the code, and the problem duplicated, and it was unfixable. So I copied the code to another new project with PBR implemented.

Comment: @Adrian May -- FredOverflow -- Marco A. -- T.C. -- Wimmel :::Thanks for your help!  I figured out it was a combination between 'passing by value' and a MS Visual Studio glitch.  Explained above. ^^^  Thanks again!!

Comment: @LazyBear And a simple rebuild did not fix this?

Comment: @FredOverflow  It did not.  That's probably why I was stuck for so long after you guys pointed me in the right direction with passing by reference.  There may be a way to fix this, but honestly I lack the finer skills in Visual Studio.  Until I got the DreamSpark acct, I was using free compilers.  Any pointers on VS front would be appreciated.

Comment: @LazyBear If your program fails to compile, Visual Studio can be configured to run the last successfull build, which is potentially very confusing. What happens if you take a working program and add obvious nonsense like `if (the sun goes down) abandon earth();`? Does Visual Studio run the previous version?

Comment: @FredOverflow  It does if the program fails to compile.  The program compiles fine, but while it is running the iterator variables still initialize with preposterous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted you're:

- Passing vectors by value
- Using something possibly uninitialized out-of-my-scope (this is nowhere declared/defined in your question) as increment variable

  ```
  //Creates a new line after every semi-colon.
  void sortLines (vector<string> row)
  {
    vector<string> tempRow;
    string tempLine;
    string tempString;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < row.size(); k++) // <-- what is k??
    {
  ```

Comment: Oh...sorry.  I tried changing i to k to see if it'd make a difference.  I just forgot to change it back before posting here.

Comment: If you have that declared but not initialized elsewhere, that'll be your problem

Comment: I SOLVED IT! And a bunch of people here helped! Okay, the problem WAS that I was passing by value, but even when I changed it the code would not work.  The actual problem was with Microsoft Visual Studio.  Once I PBV once, it corrupted my project.  No matter what I did to the code, for-loops would not work.  So I plugged the code into a new project (which I tried before posting to stackoverflow), and it worked.  Then, just to see what would happen, I deleted the &s from the code, and the problem duplicated, and it was unfixable. So I copied the code to another new project with PBR implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Why pass "string line" to removeComments? It should be local to that function cos you don't use it outside. It looks dodgy for the same reason that the passed vectors did.

Comment: Good note.  Initially that function was a stand alone project that was incorporated into this program. Not sure now why I passed it from main rather than declaring note in the function.  The problem still persists after the edit though.  This program worked when using arrays, and that copy still runs perfectly.  All the for-loops worked as usual.  I've used vectors before a bunch of times, more than likely with all these coding problems.  I've never had the program ignore a clear declaration like this.  If I code 'i = 0'in a for-loop...shouldn't 'i = 0'?  It's confusing to me.